# How to transfer the domain of an n degree polynomial to another domain

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a polynomial $\ f $ with a degree of n such that

$\ f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ..... a_nx^n $

How can I make the domain of this polynomial equals to $R^{n\times n}$?

Comment: Do you mean to write $f(x)=\sum a_ix^i$? Also, addition, scalar multiplication, and positive integer powers are all well-defined for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, so there's no issue.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal Is the answer simply to make $x$ an $n \times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define an arbitrary linear transformation to translate your polynomials into square matrices but since $dim(\mathbb P_n(\mathbb R)=n+1<dim(\mathbb R^{n\times n})=n^2$ for most $n$, the transformation won't be isomorphic and the ”translation”, if you may, will be very rough.